# Filtering everything but number between slashes with regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to filter the number from a URL and use as the value of a text field although this current regex is not entirely working:

---

Here is what I have so far:

**Form:**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search by Asset ID"   
maxlength="64" class="form-control" id="imageid" name="imageid">
```

and

```
var referrerURL = "http://subdomain.xxxxx.xxxxx.com/content/assets/750/blah";
$("#imageid").val(referrerURL.match(/assets\/(\d+)/));
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/te7jzogp/)

---

The current regex return: `assets/750,750`, while it needs to only return `750`.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're getting an array back. Simply select the result at the 1 index.

```js
var referrerURL = "http://subdomain.xxxxx.xxxxx.com/content/assets/750/blah";
$("#imageid").val(referrerURL.match(/assets\/(\d+)/)[1]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search by Asset ID" maxlength="64" class="form-control" id="imageid" name="imageid">
```

Answer (score 0):

use a ? to indicate an expression that you want to match but not return. I think it only works going forward, so you have to reverse the string first.

```
$("#imageid").val(referrerURL.split('').reverse().join('').match(/\d+(?=\/stessa)/).toString().split('').reverse().join(''));
```